# Filtering value in textarea in 'input' event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

What I want is filtering user's input. Remove newline and limit its length.

I tried two methods.

https://jsfiddle.net/mj111/356yx1df/3/

html

```
<div>
<textarea id="text1" placeholder="write down"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
<textarea id="text2" placeholder="write down"></textarea>
</div>
```

script

```
document.getElementById('text1')
.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
 evt.preventDefault(); // prevent value change
 
 const msg = evt.target.value.replace(/\n/g, '')
 if (msg.length <= 10) {
   document.getElementById('text1').value = msg
 }
})

document.getElementById('text2')
.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
 const msg = evt.target.value.replace(/\n/g, '').slice(0, 10)
 document.getElementById('text2').value = msg
})
```

First one is not working, because `preventDefault` is not working. As MDN doc [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input). 'input' event is not cancelable.

So, I tried second method; just overwrite textarea value.

I think there's a better way to do this. If anyone has a good idea, please answer.

Comment: So use a textbox with maxLength? no line feeds and no code to limit length. Problem with changing the value, it causes issue with cursor jumping.

Comment: @epascarello second one also cause cursor jumping?

Answer (score 0):

use keyup event to limit length or you can just add maxlength manually to the HTML as an attribute. If you want to set it dynamically you can use Element.setAttribute. For preventing new lines you can prevent the return key, as long as it is not shift. You can still use replace to replace things you feel need replacing, a regular expression will most effectively get the job done.

```js
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
var text1 = text[0];
var text2 = text[1];

text1.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  let val = event.target.value;
  let limit = 25;
  // limit the value once you reach a particular length
  if (val.length > 3) {
    event.target.value = val.substr(0, limit)
  };
  // prevent new line by preventing enter key press
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('no new lines please');
    return false;
  }
  // and you can filter with replace
   


})
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="text1" placeholder="write down"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <textarea id="text2" placeholder="write down"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to make users feel naturally when typing. keyup event cause cursor jumping, when keep pressing key

Comment: @MJk switch it to keydown or apply one of the many suggestions made as alternatives.